# Copy folder structure from src/ to dist/ using grunt-contrib-copy

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have a folder structure that looks like this

[image]

I want to copy the folder `img/` from `src/` to the `dist/` folder.

I use the following grunt command, using [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy):

```
copy:{
       main : {
                files : [
                    {
                        flatten : true,
                        expand: true,
                        src: ['src/img/*'],
                        dest: 'dist/img'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

But my folder structure ends up like this. Missing the images in the icons folder:

[image]

Basically, I want to do the linux command (when I'm located in the root of my project):

```
cp -r src/img dist/img
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `grunt-cp` has a recursive copy of dir. Can you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Set flatten to false `flatten : false` and change src to `['src/img/**']` to include subdirectories (source: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)

```
copy:{
   main : {
            files : [
                {
                    flatten : false,
                    expand: true,
                    src: ['src/img/**'],
                    dest: 'dist/img'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing the following:

```
copy:{

    main : {
        files : [
            {
                cwd: 'src/',
                expand: true,
                src: ['img/**'],
                dest: 'dist/'
            }


        ]
    }
}
```

Setting the `cwd` was aparently needed for this to work.